# Sorting ArrayList Collections.sort not working

Tags: java, arraylist

I can see that this topic has been heavily discussed, however, I was not able to find an answer to my problem within previous discussions.  That being said, I have a very simple problem where I want to ask a user to input a list of cities.  After being entered, I am storing the list in an ArrayList cities and using collections.sort to sort them.  For some reason, collections.sort is not sorting my ArrayList.  Example: User input is "Atlanta, Washington DC, New York".  My output, when running the program, is unsorted.

```
public class CitySortDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter as many cities as you can!");
        cities.add(input.nextLine());
        Collections.sort(cities);
        for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(cities.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have added only one city

Comment: You are only reading one line of input and add that entire line as a single element of your List. Perhaps you want to split the input line.

Comment: You don't have list of cities, just one string with cities separated with coma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can ask the user how many cities are expected to sort or specify a character that when it is seen, stop taking input and sort them. In this your code, it just takes one line as a string. For example, it takes cities until the user enters the specifier character in which the code is `!` then sort.

```
import java.util.*;

class CitySortDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String specifier = "!";
        String str;
        ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter as many cities as you can!");
        str = input.nextLine();
        while (! str.equals(specifier)) {
            cities.add(str);
            str = input.nextLine();
        }
        Collections.sort(cities);
        cities.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: Nice, demonstrating `forEach` and method references. :-) But the input has probably been specified as part of the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Your code adds a **single** string to the collection, `"Atlanta, Washington DC, New York"`. A collection with only one entry is unaffected by sorting. :-)

You probably meant to break that string up, perhaps by splitting it on a comma:

```
cities.addAll(Arrays.asList(input.nextLine().split("\\s*,\\s*")));
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/uRdo22)

That splits the one string into an array of them on a comma optionally preceded and/or followed by whitespace, and adds them all to the collection.

Comment: Or of course, don't use a collection at all, use the array from `split` and [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-)